# HorizontalScrollView is there onScrollStop() event?

Tags: android

I have the following problem.  I have placed 30+ images in a HorizontalScrollView.  I am correctly detecting onScroll() by overriding this method in HorizontalScrollView.  The problem is I need to only load those images the user is near or there will be too many downloading/in memmory etc.  So If user scrolls fast right now it starts downloading everything from start of scroll to end of scroll.  This might be a hundred images and yet at end of scroll they are only next to say 4 or 5 images.  How do I detect the stop of scrolling? and use this to kick off download?

EDIT: For slow scrolling it works perfect, but fast scrolling is the problem. If the scroll is slow then the behavior is perfect.

EDIT:  What I am doing is updating any images that are nearby in onScroll but onScroll seems to get called many many times, and its difficult to determine if the images should be updated or not from inside onScroll.  For example x=50, xPrev=49, xPrev=50, x=51 etc really for each pixel change onScroll gets called.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are moving in horizontal direction ,
 what you need to do is find the velocity of moving images and based on it load images or skip them ,
get current time in onScrollChanged method save it to a variable and find difference with old time , if distance i.e. difference in horizontal x1 and x2 is more than a certain level say screen width (experiment with it ) , then calculate velocity if the velocity is below certain level load the images or otherwise ignore ,always load images when idle i.e. when velocity is zero.

Comment: I think this solution is slightly better.  There are some advantages to doing it based on time as well as velocity, but I think this is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find anyway to detect end of scrolling but using a CountDownTimer seems to work:

I also needed to override HorizontalScrollView to add a callback IHorizontalScrollListener which is called inside onScrollView of HorizontalScrollView.  viewGroupContainer is the container LinearLayout for the ImageViews.  A scroll view can only contain directly one ViewGroup so I added all the images to the view group.  The CountDownTimer is reference maintained in the activity.

```
    hzScrollView.setScrollListener(new IHorizontalScrollListener(){

                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged to x="+l+" y="+t);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged from x="+oldl+ " y="+oldt);
                    if (scrollUpdateTimer == null)
                    {
                        scrollUpdateTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000){

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {

                                scrollUpdateTimerRunning = false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long interval) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onTick updateImageViews");
                                updateImageViews(hZScrollView, viewGroupContainer);
                            }};

                    }

                    if (scrollUpdateTimerRunning == false)
                    {
                        scrollUpdateTimerRunning = true;
                        scrollUpdateTimer.start();

                    }   

                }});
}
```